# Set Windows Server user quotas with PowerShell script

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2008, administrator, quota

I am finishing space inside my Windows 2008 R2 server so my plan was to cut users quota.

There are more than hundreds of users so doing it by hand would be boring (and I think a bit stupid).
The thing is, out of 500+ users folders (home dirs), only 8 have user quota set. The rule will be: IF the user has no homedir quota set THEN assign 600mb, ELSE IF the user has his homedir set but it's more than 600mb THEN assing the current space usage + 20mb.

Any hints? :)

Answer (score 0):

I used "dirquota" command. Googling around, it was the best solution to me!